# C++ inheritance - invalid initialization of reference type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wrote the following code:

```
class DoubleClass;
class IntClass;

class Number {
public:
    virtual Number& addInt(IntClass& x)=0;
    virtual Number& addDouble(DoubleClass& x)=0;
    virtual Number& operator+(Number& x) = 0;
};

class IntClass : public Number {
private:
    int num;
public:
    IntClass(int num) : num(num) { }
    Number& addInt(IntClass& x) { return x; }
    **Number& addDouble(DoubleClass& x) { return x; }**
    Number& operator+(Number& x) { return x; }
};

class DoubleClass: public Number {
private:
    double num;
public:
    DoubleClass(double num) : num(num) {}
    double get_number() { return num; }
    Number& addInt(IntClass& x) {
        return x;
    }
    Number& addDouble(DoubleClass& x) { return x; }
    Number& operator+(Number& x) { return x; }
};
```

Thanks Diego Sevilla, I did what you said and it worked.
One more question, I'm supposed to write the function:
Number& add(Number& x,Number& y)
Is the only way of implementing it is to do dynamic_cast for x and y for all possibilities (casting x and y to int, and if an exception is thrown then casting x to double and y to double, and so on), or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 11):

At that point the compiler doesn't know `DoubleClass` inherits from `Number`. You should separate class declaration from method implementation. For example:

```
class IntClass : public Number {
// ...

  Number& addDouble(DoubleClass& x); // Note: no implementation
};

class DoubleClass : public Number
{
// ...
};

inline Number& IntClass::addDouble(DoubleClass& x) { return x; } // Won't fail now
```

Comment: using `inline` in the `addDouble()` implementation will keep the method inlined. I think, for in-body implementations, this is the default, though I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can add `inline` too. However, inlining nowadays is not related to being defined inside the class body.

Comment: @Tilman is right. In order to keep that in the header, you actually have to put `inline` there to avoid linker errors.

Comment: Ah, Johannes, you're right. However, I didn't specify where the implementation was. I'm adding it as it seems it goes into the header file.

Comment: @Diego, I googled around and found nowhere a hint that the rule that methods defined (implemented) in the body of a class are `inline` was removed by an update of the standard. Could you give me a hint why this should be the case?

Comment: @Tilman: Well, maybe it's a matter of nomenclature. If you implement the methods inside the class, of course they're inline. However, this does not mean that the compiler actually calls the method inline.

Comment: @Diego, yes, of course it doesn't mean that - just as with methods that are defined outside the class body but with the `inline` modifier.

Comment: They are not treated as inline in the sense that the compiler doesn't generate a function for them. If it does (the compiler may select to actually put the code inline instead of generating a call), the compiler may generate a private function within this compiler unit (so inline here doesn't force the compiler to generate actual inlining code).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `DoubleClass`, so you can't do anything with the reference other than take the address of the object and pass it around.